# Knockout JS: setting value in foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to reassign an object value in foreach with click on `removePollOption` function

```
       <div data-bind="foreach: pollOptions">
         <input data-bind="value: title">
         <div data-bind="text: destroy">
         <a href='#' data-bind='click: $root.removePollOption'></a>
       </div>
```

`pollOptions` array:

```
this.pollOptions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(optionsInitialData, function(pollOption) {
  return { id: pollOption.id, title: pollOption.title, destroy: pollOption.destroy };
}));
```

but when I try to do it in function value is not changing dynamically

```
this.removePollOption = function() {
  this.destroy = true;
};
```

If i try `this.destroy(true);` I get an error `Uncaught TypeError: boolean is not a function`

Comment: how are you declaring `destroy`?

Comment: @sfletche it is from json object like `{ title: 'text', destroy: false }`

Comment: is `destroy` declared as an observable?

Comment: @sfletche `destroy` is a field of objects which are elements of array. Array is  declared like `ko.observableArray`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I understood that I should declare `destroy` as observable like

```
this.pollOptions = ko.observableArray(ko.utils.arrayMap(optionsInitialData, function(pollOption) {
  return { id: pollOption.id, title: pollOption.title, destroy: ko.observable(false) };
}));
```